# TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\views\ViewExecutable::setRequest() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, null given

Tags: views

I am trying to get number of rows in a view by executing this function in my custom module in Drupal 9.3.x:

```
function module_custom_view_count () {

    $view = Views::getView('site_images_page_1');
    $view->setItemsPerPage(0);
    $arguments = array(1,176);
    $view->setArguments($arguments);
    $view->setDisplay('page_1');
    $view->execute();
    $total_rows = count($view->result);
    
    if ($total_rows) {
    \Drupal::logger('module_custom')->notice($total_rows);
    }
}
```

And I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Drupal\views\ViewExecutable::setRequest() must be an instance of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, null given, called in
> /core/modules/views/src/ViewExecutableFactory.php on line 72 in
> Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->setRequest() (line 1804 of
> /home/ulhyooam/domains/guide/core/modules/views/src/ViewExecutable.php)

The problem is in Views::getView(), because it goes away as soon as I remove this. Removing other lines won't make any difference. Any ideas?

Comment: For some reason, there is no `request` on the stack when you get the View https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutableFactory.php/function/ViewExecutableFactory%3A%3Aget/9.3.x

Comment: It seems that `module_custom_view_count()` is called in the wrong moment. What function is calling `module_custom_view_count()`? More exactly, may you show the line that is calling `module_custom_view_count()`?

Comment: @apaderno I am calling this function right below it in the same file using this line: module_custom_view_count();